# React build is not working in subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, build, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am creating progressive web app in reactjs. When i deploy build in server subdirectory, it doesn't display anything except footer.

Here is my applied solution for subdirectory path issue. (Ref: https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1)static/chunk.css path issue is solved, but component is not rendering.Is there anything related to service worker ?

Here's App.js

```
`<BrowserRouter basename={'/buildTest'}>
                    <div>
                        <PrivateRoute exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={Artist} />
                        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Login`} component={Login} />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
<Footer />`
```

Added this in package.json

`"homepage": "http://localhost/buildTest",`

here's public/worker.js

```
`self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  if (doCache) {
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
        .then(function(cache) {
          fetch('asset-manifest.json')
            .then(response => {
              response.json();
            })
            .then(assets => {
              const urlsToCache = [
                '/',
                '../public/index.html',
                'index.js',
                'App.js',
                  'App.css'
              ];
              cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
        })
    );
  }
});`
```

Getting this error in browser and path to components not found :

```
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed`
```

terminal output after : `npm run build`

```
`> reduxapi@0.1.0 build /var/www/html/demo-pwa
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  444.21 KB  build/static/js/1.cc99dd57.chunk.js
  50.26 KB   build/static/css/1.97a0600d.chunk.css
  12.32 KB   build/static/js/main.9414fd42.chunk.js
  5.11 KB    build/static/css/main.d11e5f11.chunk.css
  768 B      build/static/js/runtime~main.04414a6d.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /buildTest/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.`
```

[please check network screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLalG.png)

I'm just looking for any possible explanation of what I might be doing wrong. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Did you try `npm run build`? Can you show the contents of the terminal after that? Are there any messages or errors in the console?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman yes i've made build using npm run build and no any errors were there

Comment: Can you share the output of terminal once you put the command please. Would be useful to guide you. 

Comment: i have added in question. Please check it.

Comment: As the error says, where's your `index.html`? I tried messaging you in FB, if I could help you by sharing screen.

Comment: inside public/index.html .Oh ! May be it's in message request so didn't noticed.

Comment: Sent you a request. Praveen Kumar it is.